# Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7

This is my first IIS publish and I got this error:

`Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. Access is denied.`

I searched the internet to see a fix to this issue with no luck.

I didn't do anything to my MVC project, I just created a new project with individual authentication and published it directly without any changes.

The way I published the project is by adding an application inside the Default Website inside IIS.

Below is the error message whenever I try to browse the app.

[image]

Comment: One of the solutions that I found on the internet is replacing the `bin` folder, I did this by copying the `bin` from my project into the published folder but it didn't work.

Comment: @MohsinMehmood the error message went away by removing the duplicates. However, I ran into another error message `The view 'Index' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched` How can I set the default rout correctly??

Comment: Does your publish folder contain `views` folder?

Comment: Yes, all of the views are there

Comment: Can you share code for your routing config?

Comment: @MohsinMehmood thank you very much for the kind support. I solved the issue, the issue caused because of the security permission on the app folder.

Comment: [Not a duplicate] This is not a duplicate question. "File could not be located" (the referenced question) is VERY different from "Access is denied." (this question).

Comment: First, you need to give your user account full control on C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files. Second, you need to go on IIS, on the application pool where the project is running change it to use custom user (enter the username and password of the account you gave full access to). Hope it helps